# What exactly is the effect of Ctrl-C on C++ Win32 console applications?

Tags: c++, winapi, console, copy-paste

1. Is it possible to handle this event in some way?
2. What happens in terms of stack unwinding and deallocation of static/global objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: SIGINT, not SIGTERM.  And Assaf reports that no objects are destroyed (at least on Windows) for unhanded SIGINT.

The system sends a SIGINT.  This concept applies (with some variance) for all C implementations.  To handle it, you call signal, specifying a signal handler.  See the documentation on the signal function at [Open Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12(vs.71).aspx) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12(vs.71).aspx).

The second question is a little trickier, and may depend on implementation.  The best bet is to handle the signal, which allows you to use `delete` and `exit()` manually.

Comment: Thanks. fyi, the MSDN page you linked to suggests that the system sends a SIGINT (and that NT upwards does not send SIGTERM at all).

Comment: Also, SIGINT, which translates into a ExitProcess, does not trigger destruction of any kind of object (global, local static, automatic). If, otoh, you translate the sigint into exit(), globals/statics will be destructor in reverse order of initialization (but automatics not).

Answer (score 13):

Ctrl-C in console application will generate a signal. The default handler of this signal calls ExitProcess to terminate the application. You can override this behaviour by setting your own handler functions for the signal using [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686016(VS.85).aspx) function.

Comment: What about deallocation of statics?

Answer (score 4):

You can test whether stack unwinding occurs, with some simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    ~A() { cerr << "unwound" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    while(1) {
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Whether it occurs not should be implementation dependant, depending on how the runtime handles the Ctrl-C. In my experience, it does not take place.

Comment: I have a hard time trusting such a test, because I'll never be sure if the behavior will differ for varying project configurations (e.g. libs, dlls, native, managed, multi-threaded and combinations thereof). So I'd rather have the "true" answer and not rely on such a test myself.

Comment: There isn't a "true" answer - the C++ Standard has nothing to say on this subject, so what you get will always be implementation dependent.

Comment: Well the true answer of VC is enough for me. But I suspect the answer may differ for various project types, as I said.